# Is it possible to use a function for error handling outside of an error?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following function in some pre-existing code, inside of a project I'm working on.

It saves a draft of the users order, should an error occur. I'd like to know if could use it outside of error handling to create a new order as a draft.

The createOrder() function below is called when a user wants to create an order from a photo.

When I try to replace createOrder() inside of createOrderFromPhoto() with createDraftOrder()

I'm met with *"cannot conform to protocol errors"* I cannot seem to satisfy no matter how many stubs I create. What is the best/correct way to leverage the functionality I want out of this?

I apologize if this is an obviously dumb question. But I'm new to the world of swift and programming, and have a lot left to learn. So if you have an answer for me. Please, explain. I want to understand so I can do better. If this is impossible please point me in the right direction <3  Thanks in advance.

```
private func createOrderDraft(callback: @escaping (OrderModel?, Error?) -> ()) {
    
    UserService.getClient(userId: self.userId) { (clientModel, error) in
        guard let clientModel = UserService.clientResults(for: self.userId).first else {
            print ("couldn't get client for id: \(self.userId)")
            return
        }
        
        //Default value selected based on the country code of the user's phone number used at registration (e.g. "+1" => "USD", "+44" => GBP)
        var currencyCode = "usd"
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let curr = realm.objects(CurrencyModel.self)
        if curr.count > 0, let agent = UserService.user(for: AuthService.userId) {//try to get from realm if loaded before
            if agent.phone?.starts(with: "+1") == true {
                currencyCode = "usd"
            }
            else if agent.phone?.starts(with: "+33") == true {
                currencyCode = "eur"
            }
            else if agent.phone?.starts(with: "+44") == true {
                currencyCode = "gbp"
            }
            else if agent.phone?.starts(with: "+375") == true {
                currencyCode = "byn"
            }
        }

        OrderService.createOrder(
            sellerId: AuthService.userId ?? "",
            buyerId: self.userId,
            shippingDetails: clientModel.shippingDetails?.detailsInput ?? ShippingService.emptyShippingDetailsInput(),
            salesTax: 0,
            shippingCost: 0,
            currency: currencyCode,
            parentOrder: nil,
            files: [],
            message: nil) { (orderModel, error) in
                
                self.viewInput.hideLoading()
                
                if let error = error {
                    //self.viewInput.show(error: error)
                    callback(nil, error)
                    return
                }
                guard let model = orderModel, let id = model.id else {
                    callback(nil, makeError(with: "Wrong order draft"))
                    return
                }
                self.orderId = id
                print("Created parent order DRAFT with id: \(id)")
                
                callback(model, nil)
                //self.updateUI()
        }
    }
}
```

```
 class func createOrder(sellerId: String,
                           buyerId: String,
                           shippingDetails: ShippingDetailsInput,
                           salesTax: Double,
                           shippingCost: Double,
                           currency: String? = "usd",
                           parentOrderId: String? = nil,
                           parentOrder: OrderModel?,
                           files: [String],
                           message: String?,
                           callback: @escaping (OrderModel?, Error?) -> Void) {
        print("create order with: \n message: \(message)\nfiles: \(files)")
        CreateOrderRequest(
                data: CreateOrderRequestData(
                        sellerUserId: sellerId,
                        buyerUserId: buyerId,
                        shippingDetails: shippingDetails,
                        salesTax: salesTax,
                        shippingCost: shippingCost,
                        currency: currency,
                        parentOrderId: parentOrderId,
                        files: files,
                        message: message
                )
        ).request { data, error in
            if let error = error {
                callback(nil, error)
                return
            }

            if let orderData = data?.createOrder {
                var order: OrderModel?

                let realm = try! Realm()

                
                if parentOrderId != nil {
                    try! realm.write {
                        if let orderModel = OrderModel.order(for: orderData.resultMap, with: realm) {
                            parentOrder?.subOrders.append(orderModel)
                            order = orderModel
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    try! realm.write {
                    if let orderModel = OrderModel.order(for: orderData.resultMap, with: realm) {
                        realm.add(orderModel, update: true)
                        order = orderModel
                    }
                }}

                callback(order, nil)
                
                return
            }

            callback (nil, makeError(with: "Wrong response data"))
        }
    }
```

```
extension PhotoViewerScreenViewController: ContextMenuScreenModuleOutput {


func createOrderFromPhoto() {
        
        guard let id = self.viewOutput?.mediaIds[self.rootView.pagesData.currentNumberOfPage ] else { return }
        if let media = MediaService.mediaFile(for: id), let file = media.file {
            self.viewOutput?.createOrder(forMedia:file)
        }
        else if let media = MediaService.media(for: id), let file = media.file {
            self.viewOutput?.createOrder(forMedia:file)
        }
        
        
        
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: Your createOrder() is a class function and createOrderDraft() is a instance function, so you can't simply replace one with the other.

Comment: Thank you, so If I where to create a new class of Draft and have it inherit from my Order Class, to receive the createOrder() class function, I could create an override function to modify it & make it have some of the functionality of my createOrderDraft(), in theory?